# Let $\,u,v,x,y\,$ be real numbers. Prove that $ux+vy\leqslant\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\!\cdot\!\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: proof-writing

I am unsure how to go about this. This is a question for a mathematical proofs class at my University and the only proofs we have been exposed to so far are direct, contrapositive, and contradictory proofs. I tried squaring both sides but that seemed futile. I also tried proof by contradiction but it didn't seem to work. Any nudge in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: Please check the statement again

Comment: Presumable one of the terms in the title should be $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$ It is certainly not true as written. Fixed, this is called the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Oh yep sorry about that. I fixed it

Comment: Squaring both sides and cancelling identical terms gives the equivalent inequality $2uxvy\le  u^2y^2+v^2x^2$ or $0\le (uy-vx)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

$ux\!+\!vy\leqslant\big|ux\!+\!vy\big|=\!\sqrt{\left(ux\!+\!vy\right)^2}\leqslant\!\sqrt{\left(ux\!+\!vy\right)^2\!+\!\left(uy\!-\!vx\right)^2}\!=$

$=\sqrt{u^2x^2+v^2y^2+u^2y^2+v^2x^2}=\sqrt{\left(u^2+v^2\right)\!\!\cdot\!\!\left(x^2+y^2\right)}=$

$=\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\!\cdot\!\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,.$

Answer (score 0):

This is the the Cauchy-schwartz inequality in $\mathbb{R^2}$ with the euclidean product.

In this particular case, there is a geometric proof based on this figure (from Wikipédia) :
[image]

Otherwise you can look for any proof of CS inequality on the internet. Consider the polynomial of variable $t$ denoted by $P(t) = (x+tu)^2+(y+tv)^2 = (x^2+y^2)+2t(xu+yv)+t^2(u^2+v^2)$ and show that its discriminant is negative.

There is probably a more elementary approach for this particular case.

Comment: Actually, that determinant could be equal to $0$.

Comment: This is included in the negative case (in my vocabulary at least). Anyway if t's 0 then there it's the equality case.

Comment: The word “negative” should mean “less than $0$”, whereas the word “nonpositive” should mean “less than or equal to $0$”.

Comment: This is different in french

Comment: But in this site web we have to write words according to their English meaning, not French one.

Comment: I am not aware of every subtilities of english conventions